# any ideas how to add text communication to my web application using asp.net vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, web-applications

HI guys

i built a web based task manager / scheduler using vb.net

i need to add a small communication part to it to allow users to send messages to each other.

below is my concept design. the question is: is this the correct way of building a simple communicator or do you have better ideas?

[image]

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted, but I'll suggest a few ways you can get un-downvoted and maybe get good answers: 1) Show us what you've tried already.  S.O. users are notoriously grumpy when asked to do someone else's work. 2) Ask a more specific question (you can then skip #1) "How do I send text over a network connection?" or something like that. 3) Don't be vague. Anywhere. "Email-like" means nothing to anyone but you.  I might be thinking Gmail-like, you might be thinking outlook express...  Try reading the FAQ at the top of the page.

Comment: thanks Cpfohl - i restructured my question. and by the way, i am the one who voted your comment up :D

Comment: Your question is still far too vague.

Comment: thanks Allara, please check the question now

Comment: Ok, it's looking better.  Is your question really about the user interface?  'Cuz, sure, why not make the interface that way.  If your users don't like it you better believe they'll let you know!

Comment: i created a table for users, table for messages that contains from and to fields. a query (getting messages for the logged in user and marked "unread") will run at the pageload and bind to gridview. pressing the button "send" will insert data into messages table in the database and clear current text. you think this is OK

Comment: @Mokokamello, I just realized why people are so confused...typically we like to avoid 'yes/no' questions because they aren't really that instructive.  Next time you have a question like "Is this OK," try asking "this is what I've done" and then give a reason you doubt it's ok.  People will flock to answer your question because then there's a teaching opportunity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think your basic design is reasonable.  The UI is logical, and what you've described of the architecture sounds reasonable.

If you're looking to send e-mail to users 'off-site' check out [this blog entry](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/using-csharp-to-send-an-e-mail-through-smtp/).

Answer (score 1):

So mokokamello

i agree with Cpfohl
you already answered your question

> i created a table for users, table for messages that contains from and to fields. a query (getting messages for the logged in user and marked "unread") will run at the pageload and bind to gridview. pressing the button "send" will insert data into messages table in the database and clear current text. you think this is OK – mokokamello 1 min ago edit i created a table for users, table for messages that contains from and to fields. a query (getting messages for the logged in user and marked "unread") will run at the pageload and bind to gridview. pressing the button "send" will insert data into messages table in the database and clear current text.

just work on the design to make it more palatable
good luck